# T-SQL. HOW to create a table with a sequence of values

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with a list of names and indices. For example like this:

```
ID |   Name  | Index
1  | Value 1 | 3 
2  | Value 2 | 4 
     ...
N  | Value N | NN
```

I need to create a new table, where every value from field "Name" will be repeat  repeated as many times as the "Index" field is specified. For example like this:

```
ID |  Name_2 | ID_2
1  | Value 1 | 1
2  | Value 1 | 2
3  | Value 1 | 3 
4  | Value 2 | 1 
5  | Value 2 | 2 
6  | Value 2 | 3 
7  | Value 2 | 4 
     ...
N  | Value N | 1
N+1| Value N | 2
    ...
```

I have no idea how to write a cycle to get such result. Please, give me an advice.

Comment: Why value 1 is repeated 3 times whereas value 2 repeated 4 times? Is it not  that it should look for index column?

Comment: An "Index" value from the 1st tane means how many times "Name" value is needed to be repeat in 2nd table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution to repeat the rows based on a column value

```
declare @order table ( Id int, name varchar(20), indx int)
Insert into @order
(Id, name, indx)
VALUES
(1,'Value1',3),
(2,'Value2',4),
(3,'Value3',2)

;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT * FROM @order

UNION ALL

SELECT cte.[ID], cte.name, (cte.indx - 1) indx
FROM cte INNER JOIN @order t
  ON cte.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE cte.indx > 1
)
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name ASC) AS Id, name as [name_2], 1 as [Id_2]
FROM cte
ORDER BY 1
```